# Symfony output image """Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."""

Tags: php, symfony1, http-headers

in /lib/Helper.class.php:

```
class Helper
{
  //... some functions
  static public function createImage( $src_image, $params)
  {
    $vars=array();
    foreach(array('angle'=>0,'font'=>'dejavu','font_size'=>20,'line_spacing'=>1.5,'preset'=>'BRCA','color'=>array(0,0,0),'text'=>'default text') as $key=>$value):

      $vars[$key]= array_key_exists($key, $params)?$params[$key]:sfConfig::get('app_default_poster_'.$key, $value);
    endforeach;

    extract($vars);
    $interval= $font_size*$line_spacing;
    $x=0;
    $y=0;
    $img_color = imagecolorallocate($src_image, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);
    $lines=explode("\n", $text);
    putenv('GDFONTPATH='.join(':',sfConfig::get('app_font_path')));
    $fontname=$font.'.ttf';
    foreach($lines as $i=>$line):

      imagettftext($src_image, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y+($i+1)*$interval, $img_color, $fontname, $line);

    endforeach;
    return $src_image;

  } 

  static public function createPoster( $params)
  {   
    $im= imagecreatefromjpeg(sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir').'/images/'.$params['preset'].'.jpg');
    return self::createImage($im, $params);
  }
  static public function createSidetape( $params)
  {

    $im= imagecreatetruecolor(sfConfig::get('app_sidetape_width'),sfConfig::get('app_sidetape_height'));
    $bg= imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($im, 0,0,$bg);
    return self::createImage($im , $params);
  } 


}
```

in my `actions.class.php` (of some module)

```
  public function executePreview(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
    $this->setLayout(false);
    $img2=Helper::createPoster($request->getGetParameters());
    imagejpeg($img2, NULL, 10); 
    return sfView::NONE;

  }
```

now when I open `/module/preview?text=Some+Text&preset=notice`, I don't see correct image but its binary data along with a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/weblog/apps/backend/modules/poster/actions/actions.class.php:253) in /var/www/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 336 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/weblog/apps/backend/modules/poster/actions/actions.class.php:253) in /var/www/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 357
```

On the other hand, if I change `$img2=Helper::createPoster($request->getGetParameters());` to `$img2=Helper::createSidetape($request->getGetParameters());` in `executePreview`, I see an image. Why?

What's the problem in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `executePreview` to the following:

```
  public function executePreview(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
    $this->setLayout(false);
    $img2=Helper::createPoster($request->getGetParameters());
    $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
    imagejpeg($img2, NULL, 10); 
    return sfView::NONE;

  }
```

The problem was occuring because Symfony first sends `Http headers` and then the `Content`. both these calls are made in the view layer of the `MVC`. Now my action was calling `imagejpeg` hence sending output to the browser even before `sendHttpHeaders` was called by the framework. So I forced it to send Http header before actually sending image as output.

Answer (score 1):

this usually happens when php outputs error / warning messages before code like

```
 $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
```

gets executed.